# dnsmasq doesn't get udp queries

Tags: networking, debian, dnsmasq

I'm trying to setup dnsmasq on debian box to serve in my local network.
dnsmasq seems to work. It listens on 53 port UDP and TCP.
It answers queries (nslookup or dig) locally, but when I try to query it from other machine I can get answers only with +tcp option.

So when I do:

```
dig @192.168.1.10 google.com +tcp
```

I can see query in dnsmasq log and I get answer.

but when I ommit +tcp option I get:

```
$ dig @192.168.1.10 +short www.google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

I cleared all iptables rules.
What can cause blocking UDP queries to dnsmasq?

Comment: Have you looked at network traffic using something like tcpdump/wireshark?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `bind-interfaces` instead of `bind-dynamic`.

Comment: Can you be more clear and specific??

Comment: @G-Man uncomment the `bind-interfaces` from `dnsmasq.conf`. The meanings of `--bind-interfaces` and `--bind-dynamic` could be found from its man page `man dnsmasq`.